Get subsequent type from generic type in if statement
I want to have a type guard that define a generic type and also the subsequent type of this generic.
enum Fruit {
    Apple = "apple",
    Banana = "banana",
}

function isApple(fruit: Fruit): fruit is Fruit.Apple {
    return fruit === Fruit.Apple;
}


interface AppleDescription {
    color: string;
    radius?: number;
}

interface BananaDescription {
    length: number;
}

type FruitDescription<T extends Fruit> = T extends Fruit.Apple ? AppleDescription : BananaDescription;

function findFruitDescription<T extends Fruit>({ fruit }: { fruit: T }): FruitDescription<T>[] {
    if (fruit === Fruit.Apple && isApple(fruit)) {
        return [{ color: "red" }] as FruitDescription<T>[]; // I'm forced to cast here, otherwise it didn't recognize the type
    } else {
        return [{ length: 10 }] as FruitDescription<T>[];
    }
}


function exemple<T extends Fruit>(fruit: T) {
    const fruitDescriptionList = findFruitDescription({ fruit });
    if (fruit === Fruit.Apple && isApple(fruit)) {
        console.log(fruit, fruitDescriptionList[0].color);
    }
}


In the "if" statement, I want ̀fruitDescriptionList` to have the type "AppleDescription" because I'm in a "isApple(fruit)" condition
I know I can do
function isAppleDescriptionList(
    descriptionList: (AppleDescription | BananaDescription)[]
): descriptionList is AppleDescription[] {
    return "color" in descriptionList[0];
}

and replace the "if" statement by fruit === Fruit.Apple && isApple(fruit) && isAppleDescriptionList(fruitDescriptionList)
But I want to know if I can avoid it.

• Your fruit === Fruit.Apple and isApple(fruit) do the same things as each other; is there a reason you do both in your examples? • Without something like ms/TS#33014 you can't use generics and control flow this way. You can refactor to use generic indexing instead of control flow as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

Yes, it works ! Thank you very much
